# Refresh PHP Page using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have a php page that needs to be refreshed every 5 secs. On embedding the ajax file, I don't find the updates taking place in Firebug. Here is the skeleton of the code:

```
**notification.php**
<?php
       ....
       ....
?>
<html>
     <head>
     <script src="./refresh.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         refreshContents();
     </script>
     </head>
     <body>
            ....

            <div id="identifier">
               <p>Waiting area</p>
            </div>
      </body>
</html>


**refresh.js**

var seconds = 5;
var content = "identifier";
var url = "notification.php";

function refreshContents()
{
   var xmlHttp;
   try
   {
      xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   catch(e)
   {
      try
      {
         xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch(f)
      {
         try
         {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }
         catch(g)
         {
            alert("Browser not supports Ajax");
            return false;
         }
      }
   }


   xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
      if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
      {
         document.getElementById(content).innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
         setTimeout('refreshContents()', seconds*1000);
      }
   }

   xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
   xmlHttp.send(null);
}

var seconds = 5;
window.onload = function startrefresh(){
   setTimeout('refreshContents()', seconds*1000);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Though it may not be the ideal solution, jQuery has a pretty simple way of implementing exactly this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function reload() {
    $("#content").load("notification.php");
  }
  setTimeOut(reload, seconds*1000)
}
```

I'm not sure that will work perfectly, haven't done it in a little while, but its a much more elegant solution I do believe.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just put a `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">` tag into your `<head>`? It will refresh the page every 5 seconds without the need for any javascript.

Comment: Because I need to fire updates as well every  5secs to the database.

Comment: Fire them in your PHP code, since it will run every time the page is refreshed

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. This is really strange !! is it because notification.php creates a cookie in the beginning?

Comment: What kind of actions does notification.php do? If you're refreshing the entire page and not just replacing some of it's contents, it makes more sense to use the `meta http-equiv="refresh"`. What kind of results do you get when you open this page?

Answer (score 1):

see the following example :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Refresh a page in jQuery</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="PageRefresh">Refresh a Page in jQuery</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#PageRefresh').click(function() {
          location.reload();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this code definetly help you.
or we can use -

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```